# Error message when correcting collected GPS data in Pathfinder office

Tags: pathfinder

I am new to this forum, but I need some help. I am not getting any help from our tech support that sold us our units.

I am post correcting the data, and I am getting two errors all the time, No carrer data, and Baseline exceeded the maximum lenght.

I had no problems before postcoreeceting data, and i am doing it the same way this time to. Is there something I am missing, or Is there a problem here.

```
Error Messages.

Carrier processing...

Maximum allowed baseline length exceeded.

Corrected 0 positions

Code processing...

Corrected 0 positions

Filtered out 2412 uncorrected positions

(only "Corrected" positions selected for output)



Processing rover file, BCTSC3KB1029A.SSF ...

...to output file, C:\Current Projects\BMO_Project\GPS\BCTSC3KB1029A_2.cor

Carrier processing...

No carrier processing performed as file has no carrier data

Corrected 0 positions

Code processing...

Corrected 0 positions

Filtered out 2412 uncorrected positions

(only "Corrected" positions selected for output)
```

Comment: Carrier data (or high accuracy) requires a short baseline (10km I think). This is the distance between the base you are using and the GPS positions. Also you are getting 'No carrier data' error which suggests that you are not collecting data for a long enough period (20 min or more).Try processing with 'Code only' and see what results you get.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of more information like the receiver are you using, your software versions, etc, I can only offer the following advice.

There are limitations on the distance between the base station and the rover.

For single-frequency receivers (Geo 6000XT, Pro XT, Pro 6T, etc), I think the Pathfinder Office 5.60 limit is 50 miles.

For dual-frequency receivers ("XH" devices, HStar devices) the limit is much higher - I've post-processed dual-frequency files with base station a couple of hundred miles away.)  The further away the base station is, the lower the accuracy.

Since you get no positions corrected by Code post-processing, either you are really far from the base station (really far = you are in USA, base station is in Europe, etc.) or more likely some problem is causing PFO to fetch the wrong data so Base data is not for the same time frame as rover data.  Check the GPS times covered by base file and rover file match.